# How can I request the "publish_actions" permission?

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

Washington Post (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=225771117449558&display=page&next=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fwpsocialreader%2F%3F&type=user_agent&canvas=1&perms=user_about_me%2Cuser_likes%2Cpublish_actions") is able to request the publish_actions permission.

It says this on Facebook:

> While in Open Graph Beta, the 'publish_actions' permission can only be requested from developers and test users of your app. The 'publish_actions' permission will be ignored if requested from any other user.

When I try requesting the permission from non-developers, this shows up:

> Logging in will not add this app's activity to Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requesting publish_actions currently works as follows

1. If your app is in the Games category and you're using the Scores and Achievements API
2. For testing the new Open Graph custom objects and actions - this will only work for developers/test users of the app who have Timeline enabled - to use it with regular users you'll have to wait until after Timeline launches and apps start getting approved to use the new APIs

Comment: (Note to future discovers of this answer: this will change once Timeline launches and the open graph APIs come out of beta)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work only when the timeline is rolled out to everyone. When is the revised date, I am not aware.

Comment: It has not been announced -- or at least I can't find the launch details anywhere.  Might be due to a trademark lawsuit.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Facebook app authentication settings, you have to updated your `fb:login-button` to request the `publish_actions permission`.

See: [Facebook Developers - Login Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)

Answer (score 1):

Request for `publish_action`

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this,Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

But on `1st, August 2018` Facebook announced new policy so, After 1st, August 2018 `publish_action` no longer available for Facebook share post programmatically.

Read More about Facebook Updated Policy: [click here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/)

Answer (score 0):

User this function

```
function postToFacebook() {
 FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'www.fb.com/mahfuzcmt',
  caption: 'bitSoft',
 }, function(response){});
}
```

and call

```
 <a href="#" onClick="postToFacebook()">Post to Facebook</a>
```

[reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog)